# Why does VLC depend on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vlc-media-player, centos-7

I am trying to install VLC on Centos 7.

However when I go to install via [these](https://www.osetc.com/how-to-install-vlc-media-player-on-centos-7-linux.html) instructions it thinks Visual Studio Code Insiders is a dependency and wants to install it.

I do use Visual Studio Code but I don't want to install the insiders edition.

```bsh
$ sudo yum install vlc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.coreix.net
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirrors.coreix.net
 * epel: lon.mirror.rackspace.com
 * extras: mirrors.coreix.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: www.mirrorservice.org
 * updates: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vlc.x86_64 1:3.0.13-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: vlc-core(x86-64) = 1:3.0.13-1.el7 for package: 1:vlc-3.0.13-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libvlccore.so.9()(64bit) for package: 1:vlc-3.0.13-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vlc-core.x86_64 1:3.0.13-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libplacebo.so.4()(64bit) for package: 1:vlc-core-3.0.13-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libplacebo.x86_64 0:0.4.0-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libvulkan.so.1()(64bit) for package: libplacebo-0.4.0-2.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package code-insiders.x86_64 0:1.57.0-1620278899.el8 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                          Arch                                      Version                                                  Repository                                                 Size
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 vlc                                              x86_64                                    1:3.0.13-1.el7                                           rpmfusion-free-updates                                    1.5 M
Installing for dependencies:
 code-insiders                                    x86_64                                    1.57.0-1620278899.el8                                    code                                                      101 M
 libplacebo                                       x86_64                                    0.4.0-2.el7                                              epel                                                      119 k
 vlc-core                                         x86_64                                    1:3.0.13-1.el7                                           rpmfusion-free-updates                                     10 M

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+3 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 113 M
Installed size: 328 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this, but since I came across the same problem, I was able to work out what happened.

`yum deplist vlc-core` tells us that vlc-core has a dependency on:

```
dependency: libplacebo.so.4()(64bit)
 provider: libplacebo.x86_64 0.4.0-2.el7
```

If we then check `yum deplist libplacebo`, we can see:

```
dependency: libvulkan.so.1()(64bit)
 provider: vulkan.x86_64 1.1.73.0-1.el7
 provider: code-insiders.x86_64 1.59.0-1627536783.el8
 provider: code-exploration.x86_64 1.58.0-1624978216.el8
 provider: code.x86_64 1.58.2-1626302881.el8
```

So VSCode provides `libvulkan`, which VLC requires. Installing `libvulkan` via `yum install vulkan` provides this library separately to VSCode.